# EL expressions are not evaluated

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, el

I have developed a java server page which has java server faces tags. It is fetching a bean data like this:

```
<h:inputText value="#{UserBean.userName}" />
```

But when I run it, it is showing the value as it is and not evaluating the value.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: <f:view>
<h1>
<h:outputText value="JSF 1.2 Tutorial"/>
</h1>
  <h:form id="UserEntryForm">
  <h:outputText value="Enter Your Name:"/>
  <h:inputText value="#{UserBean.userName}" />
  <h:commandButton action="welcome" value="OK" />
   </h:form>
</f:view> when i run in the text box it is showing     #{UserBean.userName}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the EL expressions are not evaluated and you see `#{UserBean.userName}` in the webpage instead of the evaluated value?

Ensure that your `web.xml` is declared conform the maximum supported Servlet version as supported by the webcontainer. JSF 1.2 and 2.0 requires a minimum of Servlet 2.5. JSF 2.1 requires a minimum of Servlet 3.0. The Servlet version is coupled to the EL version used. JSF 1.2/2.0 rely on the new "Unified EL" (EL 2.1) which is part of Servlet 2.5.

I'll assume Servlet 2.5, here's how the root declaration of the `web.xml` should then look like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">

    <!-- Your config here -->

</web-app>
```

A bit decent IDE can autogenerate it for you if you have properly configured the project as Servlet 2.5 project and chosen a Servlet 2.5 compatible container such as at least Tomcat 6.0.

Comment: So, the EL expressions are not evaluated and you see #{UserBean.userName} in the webpage instead of the evaluated value? exactly

Comment: I've edited your question title. Is seems that you were not understanding what exactly was happening.

Comment: Then your container doesn't support servlet 2.5 at all. Or you did not set it correctly. Or you did not rebuild/redeploy/restart the project/server. Or you have container-specific libraries in `/WEB-INF/lib` for some reason. Etc..etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are missing JSF servlet(s) in web.xml.

Here is example configuration for JSF 2.0:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">

    <description>JSF 2.0 - Hello World</description>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <!-- This is important -->
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <!-- This is important -->
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>hello.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
</web-app>
```

You might need some additional servlets for JSF 1.2, here is [example for RichFaces](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/GettingStarted.html). Please verify if your web.xml contains at least FacesServlet and if servlet mapping is done correctly. If you need farther help, please paste web.xml and faces-config.xml (if exists).

Comment: This is not correct. If the `FacesServlet` was missing or not invoked, then the OP wouldn't have seen any raw EL expressions in the rendered page. Simply because the `<h:inputText>` would then not be rendered to a `<input type="text">` and HTML doesn't recognize a `<h:inputText>`.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the servlet version (from 2.5), don't forget to see if there is in web.xml an el-ignored as true.

```
<jsp-config> 
   <jsp-property-group> 
   <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern> 
   <el-ignored>true</el-ignored> 
   </jsp-property-group 
</jsp-config>
```

or a JSP Directive in your page like this:

```
<%@ page isELIgnored="true" %>
```